# How to update image/data in nested variants in Vue .js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to change the image of my product based upon the colour user hovers , 
so here I have taken products data as variant and number of colour & image in each product as  my  item in items , but when I  Check the value of updated variable value of  variation.variationImage  as an Java script "alert" , it shows the updated path of image , but it doesn't change the value of image in reality . 
Can Any one please help me out .

Here's my html
I have Included libraries of vue.js and my js as well.

```
<div id="watch-slider" class="responsive py-5">
   <div v-for="variant in variants"  class="col-lg-4 col-4 p-4">
      <div class="watch-slider-div">
         <img :src="variant.variantImage"  class="w-100 py-3"> 
         <div :id="variant.variantId"  class="w-100 text-center">
            <div v-for="item in variant.items" :style="{ backgroundColor: item.itemcolour }" class="watch-clolours"  @mouseover="updateProduct(item.itemimage)">
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="watch-slider-txt">
            <h3>{{variant.variantname}}</h3>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here's my  js

```
var watchslider = new Vue({

   el: '#watch-slider',
   data: {
      variants: [{
            variantId: 501,
            variantImage: 'assets/images/demo_watch_1.png',
            variantname: 'alpha',

            items: [{
                  itemId: 1,
                  itemimage: 'assets/images/demo_watch_2.png',
                  itemcolour: 'gold'
               },
               {
                  itemId: 2,
                  itemimage: 'assets/images/demo_watch_4.png',
                  itemcolour: 'pink',
               },
               {
                  itemId: 3,
                  itemimage: 'assets/images/demo_watch_1.png',
                  itemcolour: 'black'
               },

            ]

         },
         {
            variantId: 502,
            variantImage: 'assets/images/demo_watch_2.png',
            variantname: 'alpha',
            items: [{
                  itemId: 1,
                  itemimage: 'assets/images/demo_watch_2.png',
                  itemcolour: 'gold'
               },
               {
                  itemId: 2,
                  itemimage: 'assets/images/demo_watch_4.png',
                  itemcolour: 'pink',
               },
               {
                  itemId: 3,
                  itemimage: 'assets/images/demo_watch_1.png',
                  itemcolour: 'black'
               },

            ]
         }
      ]

   },
   methods: {
      updateProduct(itemimage) {
         this.variants.variantImage = itemimage
         alert(this.variants.variantImage + '+' + itemimage);
      }
   }


});
```

Basically I want  to update my product image based upon the colour image user hovers from he items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must specify exact index of your object that you want to change it.

Please look at this example

```js
var watchslider = new Vue({
   el: '#watch-slider',
   data: {
      variants: [{
            variantId: 501,
            variantImage: 'https://picsum.photos/200',
            variantname: 'alpha',
            items: [
               {
                  itemId: 1,
                  itemimage: 'https://picsum.photos/100',
                  itemcolour: 'gold'
               },
               {
                  itemId: 2,
                  itemimage: 'https://picsum.photos/130',
                  itemcolour: 'pink',
               },
               {
                  itemId: 3,
                  itemimage: 'https://picsum.photos/120',
                  itemcolour: 'black'
               },
            ]
         },
         {
            variantId: 502,
            variantImage: 'https://picsum.photos/200',
            variantname: 'alpha',
            items: [{
                  itemId: 1,
                  itemimage: 'https://picsum.photos/110',
                  itemcolour: 'gold'
               },
               {
                  itemId: 2,
                  itemimage: 'https://picsum.photos/120',
                  itemcolour: 'pink',
               },
               {
                  itemId: 3,
                  itemimage: 'https://picsum.photos/100',
                  itemcolour: 'black'
               },

            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   methods: {
      updateProduct(variantIndex,itemimage) {
         this.variants[variantIndex].variantImage = itemimage
      }
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="watch-slider" class="responsive py-5">
   <div v-for="(variant,variantIndex) in variants"  class="col-lg-4 col-4 p-4">
      <div class="watch-slider-div">
         <img :src="variant.variantImage"  class="w-100 py-3" style="height:100px"> 
         <div :id="variant.variantId"  class="w-100 text-center">
            <div v-for="item in variant.items" style="height:50px" :style="{ backgroundColor: item.itemcolour }" class="watch-clolours"  @mouseover="updateProduct(variantIndex,item.itemimage)">
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="watch-slider-txt">
            <h3>{{variant.variantname}}</h3>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes this works but  But now it's only changing the image of First  variant with id [0]  only even if I hover on  other  variant colors, I want to change  image of  variant  whose colors I hover on  without affecting other variants.

Comment: Yes I checked But It's changing the image of first one whose ID it's picking as [0] only not other products/variants

Comment: @PardumanRana i solve this problem. check again. look at to :   @mouseover="updateProduct(variantIndex,item.itemimage)

Comment: It's working now with variantIndex  Thanks alot for solving this problem  .